# How Can I query a table from DynamoDb

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, databricks, dynamodb-queries

I am trying to get items from DynamoDb Table using Pyspark. However, I`m getting some errors:

What is the best way to do that?

I want to get values from a table using userId as a parameter.

Ex:

```
import boto3

# Get the service resource.
#dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
access_key = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "xxx", key = "sss")
secret_key = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "xxx", key = "sss")

client = boto3.resource('dynamodb',aws_access_key_id=xxx, aws_secret_access_key=xxx, region_name='us-east-1')
```

I have tried to get using get_item, query and scan. But no success.

This query returns null

```
table = client.Table('Table')
response = table.query(
    IndexName='userIndex',
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('userId').eq('321323132313-3213131'))
  
print(response['Items'])
```

Another try:

```
table = client.Table('PersonalizedOffers')

response = table.get_item(Key={
  Key={'personalizedOfferId': 'ffsaffaffafsafsafsaf',
       'userId': '3213214214141' 
})
```

I also tried to use scan

```
response = table.scan()
```

Comment: An unfiltered `scan()` operation will always work, and return all items, potentially paginated. What result are you seeing from `scan()`?

Comment: its working now! do you know how can  I get the total of results ( count ) ?

Comment: This should help for queries: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.Count